# Create div using jquery with fade in effect

Tags: jquery

I want to get some text from php file and display on a browser using jquery such that each time a new row will add at top of other and with fade in effect:
I write a script like:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
    var html = $("#response").load("new_feed.php");
    $("#foo").append("<div>"+html+"</div>");
    $("#foo").fadeIn('slow');
}, 1000);
}

<div id="foo" align="left"></div>
```

but it just create a div at once and display output like:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
...
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to work with newly created div, you're applying `fadeIn` effect to `#foo`. Try this:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get("new_feed.php", function(result) {
            $("<div></div>")
                .hide()
                .html(result)
                .prependTo("#foo")
                .fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

As you can see I use `.get()` not `.load()`. Because `.load()` function loads content to matching selector. In your case it gets content from `new_feed.php` tries to load it's contents to `#response` (I don't know if it's exists).

`.load()` function returns jQuery object, therefor when you assign it to `html` variable you see `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [`$.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [`$.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)?

## HTML

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

## jQuery

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $("<div/>").hide().load("http://fiddle.jshell.net/salman/KPG9M/show/", function() {
            $(this).prependTo("#foo").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Eq8SB/)

Comment: It'll be better if you `prepend` and `fadeIn` in `.load()`'s `success` callback due to it's async behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Its may also work like this. check it out.

```
$("#foo").append("<div>"+html+"</div>").show('slow');

                         OR

$("#foo").append("<div>"+html+"</div>").fadeIn('slow');
```

This may helpful to you..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are using it incorrectly. I'll try to explain. Basically html is set as the jquery object now, not the actual response. What you are doing is loading the html into the node with the id response. You should be able to do something like

```
var html = ''
$().load("new_feed.php",  function(response, status, xhr) {
   html = response;
});
```

Also, this would probably work too, because html is the jquery node, try it like this instead.

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
    var node = $("#response").load("new_feed.php");
    $("#foo").append("<div>"+node.html()+"</div>");
    $("#foo").fadeIn('slow');
}, 1000);
}

<div id="foo" align="left"></div>
```

Comment: sorry but not helpful.. it shows null null ... null although firebug display correct response send by the new_feed.php